# Facebook Graph search results don't match "Public Posts" results?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

It seems like the results obtained using graph.facebook.com don't match what you get from their own search results.

For example:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=www.mightytrainer.com&type=post&limit=25

versus

https://www.facebook.com/search/results.php?q=www.mightytrainer.com&type=eposts&init=quick&tas=0.07711535459384322

Neither Joe Goodwin or Taryn Higgan have mutual friends with me. They show up in the web results, but not in the graph.

Am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the same search with a user access token, the results should be similar, with respect to users privacy settings.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=www.mightytrainer.com&type=post&limit=25&access_token=your_user_access_token
```

example in Graph Explorer.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dwww.mightytrainer.com%26type%3Dpost

**refer to:** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/

php example: assumes php sdk 3.1.1. is installed, and application is setup.

```
    // init sdk, sample coming
    require './src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'Your App Id Here',
      'secret' => 'Your App Secret Here',
      'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
      ));      
    try { $user = $facebook->getUser(); } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {  }
    // Get the current access token if user.
    if($user){ 
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); 
    // in the case of ajax we need to set the access token or will get expired error.
    // Comment out api get token, uncomment session.
    // $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_YourAppIdHere_access_token']; 
    if($access_token){ $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token); }
    };
    // access token usage should be handled by api.
    $api_search = $facebook->api('/search?q=www.mightytrainer.com&type=post');
// print results array  
echo '<pre>';
print_r($api_search);
echo '</pre>';
```

javascript example:

```
// init sdk, sample coming
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn - how does one get a user (eg mine) access token? I can login via the JS/PHP combo, but the information I get back from querying /me has no info on a user token.

Comment: Good question, both js and php sdk handle the access_token.  I will edit in some information about both methods in my answer.

Comment: Very interesting - thanks!

If I may ask, is the access token you get temporary? If I set it, can I save it offline and then use it 5 days later?

Comment: No @SolOrwell access_tokens typically expire within 2 hours, with an option of exchange for a longer lived token.. see extended tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

How could facebook graph api know which user are you?
You have to provide your access token of any valid app!

Just add access_token=$token and you will get the search results as you get in your account.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=www.mightytrainer.com&type=post&limit=25&access_token=$token
```

I hope it helped. If it worked, consider accepting my answer.